# How can import custom ontology and make RDF graph according to that schema in local Virtuoso server

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have set up a [DBpedia 3.9](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/datasets/data-set-39) mirror with [Virtuoso 7.2.1](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) in my local PC. Now I make an ontology schema (**`abc.owl`**) for my own data and want to make RDF network according to that schema. I make RDF triples for my data according to that ontology and I know the method to add triples to virtuoso server.
I have added **`abc.owl`** using

```
ld_add('/usr/local/data/datasets/abc.owl','http://MyGraph.in/resource/classes#');
```

Then some triples are added using  **`curl`** -

```
curl --noproxy <server_IP> -i -d "INSERT IN GRAPH <http://MyGraph.in>{<http://MyGraph.in/ontology/resource/Rabindranath_Tagore> rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                                                  <http://MyGraph.in/ontology/#Author> ;
                                                         rdfs:label \"Rabindranath\ Tagore\"@en .} " 
-u "demo:demo" -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-query" http://<server_IP>/DAV/home/dba/xx
```

But I am unable to connect **`abc.owl`** to those triples so that I can establish class-subclass hierarchy and property-subproperty hierarchy. Please help.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why you'd be working with [DBpedia from 2013](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/changelog#3.9) and [Virtuoso from 2015](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#2015-06-24%20-%20Virtuoso%20Open-Source%20Edition%207.2.1%20Released) instead of current versions of each… That aside, I'm not clear what you mean by "connect `abc.owl` to those triples"; maybe [this article](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideOWLIinfLinkedVocab) will point you in the right direction?

Comment: I will set up  Virtuoso 7.2.4. and DBpedia 2014 . Thank you for mention. Actually I have done this set up 2 years before. 
I want to import my own ontology schema which is in file  **abc.owl**  and make RDF graph for my own dataset according to the ontology. I already have made RDF triples for my dataset and now need to set up an endpoint in local virtuoso server so that I can do SPARQL query on that. Please help.

Comment: Did you look at [the article I linked above](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideOWLIinfLinkedVocab)? Possibly you want [_inference_ and/or _reasoning_](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSPARQLReasoningTutorial) across your data?